# Field Validation for specific input

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am trying to validate a field based on the value for a partner referral code.

I have tried using the code below for my smart capture form on cloud pages from marketing cloud.

```
<script>
        function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["smartcapture-block-kxnnlxjo93j"] 
["PartnerCode"].value;
if (x == "SJC") {
return true;
} else { 
alert("Invalid Partner Referral Code - Make Sure You Use All Caps");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```

The form just submits, even if I don't use a partner code, or if I input the incorrect partner code.

The form id is "smartcapture-block-kxnnlxjo93j" and the input field id is "partnercode" that I want the function to execute on.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, you can get the value directly from the input field.

```
<script>
        function validateForm() {
  var x = document.getElementById("PartnerCode").value;
if (x == "SJC") {
return true;
} else { 
alert("Invalid Partner Referral Code - Make Sure You Use All Caps");
return false;
}
}
</script>
```